# Min\max validation issue in numeric input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

I'm using this component for all my numeric inputs https://github.com/JayeshLab/vue-numeric-input

I have the following issue: Let's say I set the validation minimum to 700 and the maximum to 800. The user cannot enter values using the keyboard. Because when she hits a digit, the value will be set to 800. And if she erases the digit, the value will be set to 700.

Is there any way to prevent min\max validation after the keypress event, and wait until blur?

Comment: could you set :controls="false" and tell if the problem persists

Comment: If you look at the open vs closed issues on the package you'll notice it has pretty big unresolved reported bugs and shortcomings. It's good you opened an issue on the repo, but I wouldn't hold my hopes high, considering the past activity and response to previously raised issues. To address your question, what you want is not possible on current version, as the component doesn't have this feature. You could fork it and add the feature yourself.